# Angular 2 + Auth0 (Could not find a declaration file for module 'auth0-js'. )

Tags: angular, auth0

**Could not find a declaration file for module 'auth0-js'. 'C:/sandbox/loginauth0/node_modules/auth0-js/src/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.**

I wanted to use the auth0 login. But after following the instructions and building my own Angular 2 service.

**import * as auth0 from 'auth0-js';**

gives an error like above. but I put it in with "npm install --save auth0-js" and its in my node_modules

Answer (score 2):

First, be sure you turn off the property **noImplicitAny** in tsconfig.json.

Then, verify you are following the steps here: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2

Answer (score 1):

Auth0.js doesn't yet provide TypeScript type definition file. You can try using:

```
const auth0 = require('auth0-js');
```

or the more brute-force method of turning the `noImplicitAny` flag to `false` in your `tsconfig.json` file, but that turns off warnings/errors for the whole project. See more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#noimplicitany-and-suppressimplicitanyindexerrors).

Comment: thank you for your help. but its still not working. It still says 

404 GET /node_modules/auth0-js/index.js . I even tried to put:                             'auth0-js':  'node_modules/auth0-js/index.js' in my systemjs.config.js

Comment: I am facing the same issue. I get 404. File is in its place.